# Importing Modules vs. Executing Scripts for Global Variables

Tags: python, module

Is it bad practice to execute a script `execfile(XX.py)`, rather than `import XX` as a module? The reason I'm interested, is that executing the file puts the functions directly into `__main__`, and then globals are available without needing to explicitly pass them. But, I'm not sure if this creates trouble... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's bad practice, for the very reason that everything ends up in `__main__`. If you have two modules which have any variable with the same name, one will overwrite the other.